# Using macros with bazel build

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-rules

I am using macro for enabling logging in my code. Also, I am using bazel build.
Currently i need to change my .cpp file to include `#define` to enable this macro. Is there a way that i can provide this alongwith `bazel build` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to control the `#define` directly with the [`--cxxopt` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--cxxopt).

Consider for example this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifndef _MY_MESSAGE_
    #define _MY_MESSAGE_ "hello"
#endif


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cerr << "message: " _MY_MESSAGE_ "\n";

#ifdef _MY_IDENTIFIER_
    std::cerr << "if branch \n";
#else
    std::cerr << "else branch \n";
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Building without flags should result in the following:

```sh
> bazel build :main
...
> ./bazel-bin/main
message: hello
else branch
```

While by settings the flags:

```sh
> bazel build --cxxopt=-D_MY_IDENTIFIER_ --cxxopt=-D_MY_MESSAGE_="\"hi\"" :main
> ./bazel-bin/main
message: hi
if branch
```

Same applies to `bazel run`:

```sh
> bazel run --cxxopt=-D_MY_IDENTIFIER_ --cxxopt=-D_MY_MESSAGE_="\"hi\"" :main
...
message: hi
if branch
```

(tested only on linux)